# What is the autocorrelation of a squared Gaussian process?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $ {X_t; t \in R} $ is a wss, zero mean Gaussian random process with autocorrelation function $ R_X( \tau) ;   \tau \in R$ and power spectral density $S_X(\omega); \omega \in R$. If w define the random process ${Y_t;t\in R} $ by ${Y_t = ({X_t}^2)}$

What is the autocorrelation function of $Y_t$ (in terms of $\tau$)?

Answer (score 6):

If $X_t$ and $X_{t+\tau}$ are jointly Gaussian with means $0$, variances $\sigma^2$ and covariance $c$, then $\text{Cov}(X_t^2, X_{t+\tau}^2) = 2 c^2$.  One way to get this is from [Isserlis's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%E2%80%99_theorem).

Comment: I think he/she asked autocorrelation, not autocovariance.

Comment: I hope he/she knew how to get correlation from covariance and variances.